# Best way to automatically determinate user language

Tags: java, android, locale

I'm developing a project where I need to automatically determinate which is the user language used to created the content.

We're actually using `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` but this can not be the right choice because, for istance, I live in Italy, I write content in Italian but my default Locale on my phone is en_US.

So I tought that maybe I could determinate it from the SIM Country (and fallback to user Locale when the device does not have one) but there's no one-to-one relation from a Country to a Language. For istance, US has en_US and es_US.

Do you have any suggestion? Should I ask the user for their current content's Locale?

Comment: if your phone is en_US, I guess you would like to have the en_US content for all apps

Comment: Honestly, if you expect your application to be used by different nationals, asking for Locale is the best option. If you have a Korean who lives in the United States that bought a phone from China, how do you determine what locale should be set?

Answer (score 6):

What's the *reason* you need the user language?

I too have my locale set to en_US, and I have that because I prefer to have menus etc in English. (The translation of menus and settings etc feels strained in my native language.)

Chances are that your users will be annoyed (I know I would) if you use anything other than `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` for whatever you're using the language for.

That being said, if you really want to use a local language, I suggest you figure out the country code by some heuristics based on

- Default locale
- SIM country
- Current network country

and use a hard coded lookup table from country code to (one of) the official language code(s). There are open databases with this information, see for example these resources:

- [List of language codes by country](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/list-of-language-codes-by-country)
- [Country codes / language codes on the OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Country_Codes)